Example 5c from A first course to probability by Sheldon Ross.

Suppose there are m days in a year, and that each person is independently born on m day r with probability $p_r$, r = 1,..., m,$\sum_{r=1}^{m}Pr = 1$. Let $A_{i,j}$ be the event that persons i and j are born on the same day.(a) Find $P(A_{1,3})$. (b) Find $P(A_{1,3}|A_{1,2}).$

Solution
(a) Because the event that 1 and 3 have the same birthday is the union of the m mutually exclusive events that they were both born on day we have that
$$P(A_{1,3})=\sum_rp^2_r$$
(b) $$ P(A_{1,3}|A_{1,2}) =\frac{P(A_{1,2}A_{1,3})}{P(A_{1,2})}
$$
$$ =\frac{\sum_rp^3_r}{\sum_rp^2_r} $$
I understand that each being born of each date is mutually exclusive event like person born. Two dates can't occur simultaneously. But how he found the union of these mutually exclusive event  and intersection.

Maybe worth noting:  At first, it might seem that the answer to $(b)$ is just $P(A_{1,3})$.  After all, person $2$ is independent of the others so how can it matter when $2$ was born?  But, knowing that $1,2$ share a birthday is evidence that $1$ was born on a more likely day, so knowing that $A_{1,2}$ happened increases the probability that $A_{1,3}$ also happened.  If all days are equally probable then the independence claim is valid.

The event that person one and person 2 have the same birthday intersected with person 1 and person 3 have the same birthday is just The event that person 1,2,3 have their birthday on the same day. This is the union of the events that person 1,2,3 have their birthday on day r, for each r. These events are all disjoint.

how to find probability that two people have same birthday.

$A_{i,j} = \cup_{k=1}^{ r} \text{(Person i and j are both born on day k)}$.    Since this events are disjoint the probability is the sum
